# Prove $\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{c+a}}\gt1$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Prove that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{c+a}}\gt1$, where a, b, c >0.

I tried,
$\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{c}{c+a}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b}\sqrt{b+c}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c}\sqrt{c+a}} \ge \frac{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b}\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c}\sqrt{c+a}}$.

Then $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a+b} \le \sqrt{2}/2 (2a+(a+b))$.

This only gave me $\sqrt{2}/2 + \sqrt{2}(\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c})$.

Comment: Yeah, I tried times $\sqrt(a)$ top and bottom, apply Titu's, then denominator sqrt(a(a+b)) using AM-GM.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore please don't post this four word question, as it can be [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/259305) by a single flag.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 ok thanks for telling,originally the OP had not shown any work but later an edit was made.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\dfrac{a}{a+b} > \dfrac{a}{a+b+c}$

Comment: I think the following is better: $\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}>\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}.$

Comment: @Michael Rosenberg: Sure is. I leave it for OP to fill

Comment: Got it. $a+b\lt(\sqrt(a)+\sqrt(b)+\sqrt(c))^2$. Much thanks.

Comment: @lilige  Show your attempts and I'll show another solutions. The same words I can say about the following your topic. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3887062/

Comment: Michael, I assumed I had to use Cauchy. So I tried times (√) top and bottom, apply Titu's, then denominator sqrt(a(a+b)) using AM-GM. That didn't get me "1". Looking forward to your "another solution".

Comment: @lilige   Add it in your open post. Also, show, how exactly you made these things.

Comment: Michael, I added to my initial post.

Comment: @lilige  I posted. There are another solutions of your problem. I see someone wants to close your beautiful topic. We'll wait. If it not will happen, I'll post these solutions.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I voted to close as a duplicate because the same inequality has been solved before (in fact by you). That has nothing to do with “beauty,” even the best question can be a duplicate. It would be better if you voted to close (and extend your older answer, if appropriate) instead of posting two more answers here.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. It's fine to close it to clean things up. I'm new here - I'll practice "vote to close" myself next time.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a+b}}>\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}>\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=1.$$

Comment: I got this way. This is what you said "better" earlier. Thank you.

Comment: @lilige You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

We can use also your idea, but in another writing:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a(a+b)}}{a+b}>\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a\cdot a}}{a+b}>\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c}=1.$$

Comment: Right! Since the inequality is not "tight", I could just throw away some terms in numerator or add positive terms in the denominator, each ends up different way to solve. Very nice. And thanks a lot.